# Deploy contract from command line

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-deployment, abi, command-line

Is there any command or utility to deploy contract from .sol file to test-net? I've seen there is JSON API, so I can write some code to implement this. But isn't it done already?

Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

[Truffle Framework](http://truffleframework.com/) is the most popular tool that is available now to perform such a task. All you need is to copy your contract code into `contracts` directory, add an entry into migration file and run:

```
truffle migrate
```

The procedure is explained in details [here](http://truffle.readthedocs.io/en/beta/getting_started/migrations/).

There are lots of tutorials and good [docs](http://truffle.readthedocs.io/en/beta/) available if you get lost.

I hope it helped

Comment: truffle has same problem as remix (thats why I tried asking) https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/492

Comment: Have you created and unlocked `default` (eth.accounts[0]) account?

Comment: Yes, I tried from command line: personal.unlockAccount("0x6c92c4201bbafe97011c9ea9144c907fd16f5089","my_pass_here"), it returned true, but still can't connect.

Comment: Have you got any ether on the account and are you sure that the client is synced to the current network state?

Comment: Yes, I have 1ETH and account is in sync: http://imgh.us/account_3.png

Comment: Can you connect with web3-js and send some eth to any other account?

Answer (score 1):

You can use node or geth to deploy a contract.

Node example:

```
npm install ethereum-js-testrpc web3
npm install solc
```

Run the test rpc server

```
node_modules/.bin/testrpc
```

Console

```
Web3 = require('web3')
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
code = fs.readFileSync('Voting.sol').toString()
solc = require('solc')
compiledCode = solc.compile(code)
abiDefinition = JSON.parse(compiledCode.contracts[':NameofYourClass'].interface)
Contract = web3.eth.contract(abiDefinition)
byteCode = compiledCode.contracts[':NameofYourClass'].bytecode
deployedContract = Contract.new(args,to,init,your,contract)
deployedContract.address
```

Comment: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/ethereum-js-testrpc

Comment: my bad, the correct command is npm install ethereumjs-testrpc web3